# SwiftUI inactivity timer

Tags: swiftui, timer, touch-event, user-inactivity

I want to show a hint after the user hasn't touched a screen for 30 seconds. For this `restartInactivityTimer()` function needs to be called whenever the screen is touched.

Is there a way to discover any screen touch to restart the timer, but without "consuming" it's tap gesture? Do I really need to call `restartInactivityTimer()` from **every `onTapGesture` (sub)view closure**, like in the code snippet below?

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var inactivityTimer: Timer?

    var body: some View {
        VStack { 
            subView1
            subView2
            subView3
            subView4
        }
        .onAppear {
            restartInactivityTimer()
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            // not reaching here when any subView is touched
            restartInactivityTimer() 
        }
    }

    func restartInactivityTimer() {
        inactivityTimer?.invalidate()
        inactivityTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 30.0, repeats: false) { _ in
            showHint()
        }
    }

    var subView1: some View {
        // ...
        .onTapGesture {
            // ... other actions for tapping that subview
            restartInactivityTimer()
        }
    }

    // ... other subviews
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most solutions I see detect user activity by overriding `UIApplication.sendEvent` ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35759301/5133585)). We can't do that easily in SwiftUI, but it *is* possible if you do method swizzling. That is quite hacky though.

You can swizzle the methods just before your app launches by writing your own entry point.

```
@main
struct EntryPoint {
    // swizzle here
    static func main() {
        let original = class_getInstanceMethod(UIApplication.self, #selector(UIApplication.sendEvent))!
        let new = class_getInstanceMethod(ActivityDetector.self, #selector(ActivityDetector.mySendEvent))!
        method_exchangeImplementations(original, new)

        // launch your app
        YourApp.main()
    }
    
}

struct YourApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

The swizzled method is:

```
class ActivityDetector: NSObject {
    
    private typealias SendEventFunc = @convention(c) (AnyObject, Selector, UIEvent) -> Void
    
    @objc func mySendEvent(_ event: UIEvent) {
        // call the original sendEvent
        // from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61523711/5133585
        unsafeBitCast(
            class_getMethodImplementation(ActivityDetector.self, #selector(mySendEvent)),
            to: SendEventFunc.self
        )(self, #selector(UIApplication.sendEvent), event)

        // send a notification, just like in the non-SwiftUI solutions
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .init("UserActivity"), object: nil)
    }
}
```

Now in your view, you can listen for the notification:

```
@State var presentAlert = false
@State var timer = Timer.publish(every: 60, on: .current, in: .common).autoconnect()

var body: some View {
    Text("Foo")
        // time is up!
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            presentAlert = true
            timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
        }
        // user did something!
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .init("UserActivity")), perform: { _ in
            timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
            timer = Timer.publish (every: 5, on: .current, in: .common).autoconnect()
        })
        .alert("Foo", isPresented: $presentAlert) {
            Button("OK") {}
        }
}
```

Using `Timer.publish` here is kind of wasteful, since you only need one output from the publisher. Consider using a `Task` for example:

```
@State var presentAlert = false
@State var task: Task<Void, Error>?

var body: some View {
    Text("Foo")
        .onAppear {
            resetTask()
        }
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .init("UserActivity")), perform: { _ in
            task?.cancel()
            resetTask()
        })
        .alert("Foo", isPresented: $presentAlert) {
            Button("OK") {}
        }
}

@MainActor
func resetTask() {
    task = Task {
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(60))
        try Task.checkCancellation()
        presentAlert = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Sweeper for your comprehensive answer. The solution presented is more hacky and swizzling than the original solution is tiresome. I was hoping for a clever something like `.onScreenActivation()` modifier. Maybe it is still ahead of Apple to develop.

Comment: @Voyteck Not even the UIKit solutions have “clever something like `.onScreenActiviation`”. Also, “swizzling” is not an adjective here. It just means exchanging the implementations of two methods.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Using .onTapGesture will not catch all user input.